# File.isFile() returns incorrect result?

Tags: java, file

```
public class Test {
  public static void isFile() {
    System.out.println(new File("D:\\a.log").isFile());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new File("‪D:\\a.log").isFile());
    isFile();
  }
}
```

The expected result is:

```
true
true
```

but actually the result is:

```
false
true
```

The file D:\a.log is actually exist and the path is correct, the jdk version is 1.8.0_11, and the os is win10

How to understand this??

Comment: check File.exists() and File.canRead()

Comment: Your code returns only `true` for a file if it exists

Comment: Try to store the path in a `String` variable that you will use in both methods, maybe one of your paths has e.g some zero width character inside it.

Comment: returns true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a normal file; false otherwise, see [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29)

Comment: @Arnaud Your comment gives rise to 6-up-voted answer. Nice advice +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The string `"‪D:\\a.log"` inside the `main` method has 9 characters, the one in the `isFile` method has 8 characters.

The one inside the `main` method starts with invisible unicode character U+202A ("LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING").

Replace the string inside `main` with the string inside `isFile`, or delete the first invisible character from the string in `main`.

(Note: this shows the real benefit of copy-pasting your actual code, as the problem is in the code that you pasted in your question above)

Comment: Impressive! How did you detect it ?? Would mind explaining ?? +1

Comment: Humm, maybe from Arnaud's answer.

Comment: @snr : You may for instance copy-paste that code in a file, and use an hex editor to see what it contains exactly .

Comment: You can have it even simpler. Open the the Object/DOM Inspector of your browser and compare both paths. The last one shows: `<span class="str">"&#8234;D:\\a.log"</span>`

Comment: @snr simply by looking at the string lengths and when I saw they were different, by printing the character values. It was the only possibility- files don’t magically get created between method calls.

Comment: @snr I'm going to point out the [StackOverflow "Be Nice" policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) to you, I suggest you have a read through it. I'll also flag your comment. Maybe it didn't occur to you that some problems are obvious to (multiple) experienced people, because there is no other possible reason for something - as I said, files don't just appear out of the blue between method calls. And if you read through my answers, you'll see that I'm well aware of the intricacies of the Unicode character set.