# Why is this file path wrong?

Tags: java

I am working on an app and I have to use a certificate and this is the code :

```
File f = new File("‪‪D:\\john.doe.pfx");
```

When I run the app it gives me this error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪‪D:\john.doe.pfx (The filename, directory 
name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at testoauth.TestOAUTH.main(TestOAUTH.java:58)
```

The certificate was in a folder called "proiect oauth" and i got it out and put it directly in D:

I would like to use the file and not give error

Comment: @Gimby -- oopsss

Comment: Please check, if the file named "`D:\john.doe.pfx`" is there and is accessible by the user.
Just copy it in your clipboard, press Windows-R and paste it. 
It should open, either in editor, keystore-app or dialog which asks what to do with this file. Explorer can mislead you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I moved the certificate to D: without being in any folders

Comment: Hm, show an image of the file explorer

Comment: Indeed, the simplest answer is that the file is not actually named john.doe.pfx. How silly it may sound. It might be something you don't actually see, like there being a space in the filename.

Comment: The string you are using has invisible unicode characters in it. ```new File("\u202a\u202aD:\\john.doe.pfx");```. Remove those invisible characters at the start.

Comment: Note that when a file does not exist, the exception thrown is `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\john.doe.pfx` (with nothing afterwards). Here it explicitly says `syntax is incorrect`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File.isFile() returns incorrect result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627022/file-isfile-returns-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 13):

The string you are using has invisible unicode characters `\u202a` at the start.

It is as if you had:

```
new File("\u202a\u202aD:\\john.doe.pfx");
```

which is not the correct path.

Retype the line and omit the invisible characters at the start.

Comment: Being curious: where do you know from?

Comment: @SirFartALot The invisible characters are there in the OP's code.

Comment: @SirFartALot copy-paste the string from the question and delete characters one by one.

Comment: [Why is there an invisible U+202A at the start of my file name?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150506-00/?p=44924)

Comment: How/why did they get in there in the first place?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Johnny Mopp's link seems to (try to) explain that. It does not help me to lower my eyebrow.